# Raspberry Pi - Mac - PyCharm

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pycharm

I am a new Raspberry Pi user.

I want to run my code that is written in MacBookPro, on Raspberry Pi. In other words, I write my code in my MacBookPro (by using PyCharmEdu ide) and run ıt on Raspberry Pi which connected to my computer.

First question is: Is it possible?
if yes
Second question is : How can I do?

I know it is a bit board question so any link that explain how, will be appreciated.

PS1 : I have already checked many blogs and and videos but I could not find a answer.
PS2 : My second step will be make a cluster so if you have answer for pi cluster (I can buy few more raspberry pi and) jump to that problem

Comment: This is not a programming question so it's the wrong place to ask this. You should delete it to prevent negative points. There's a Raspberry Pi area on stack overflow which would be a better place to ask.(And the professional version of PyCharm can do remote exection, not sure about the others)

Comment: You can do it. You activate ssh in raspberry. PyCharm can run/deploy via ssh (common to real server, but it should works also on Pi).

Comment: @576i Thank you for your warning. I thought I should write a program to solve this issue. Hence I asked here. I indeed will ask in the other site.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thank you. I will work on ssh and update the results.

Comment: @576i: this site is about programming and **programmer's tools** (and PyCharm is not something people have on Raspberry Pi)